# How can I group an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array :

```
array=[{x:2,y:test0,z:title},{x:3,y:test0,z:title},{x:4,y:test0,z:title},{x:5,y:test0,z:title2},{x:6,y:test0,z:title2},{x:7,y:test0,z:title2}]
```

And I turned it into this array this way:

```
 const groups = array.reduce((acc, row) => {
       acc[row[title]] = acc[row[title]] || [];
        acc[row[title]].push(row);
        return acc;
      }, {});
```

this is result:

```
  [
    title:[{x:2,y:test0},{x:3,y:test0},{x:4,y:test0}]
    title2:[{x:5,y:test1},{x:6,y:test1},{x:7,y:test1}]
    ]
```

And I want to have this array:

```
[
 title:[test0:[{x:2},{x3:},{x:4}]]
 title2:[test1:[{x:5}],test2:[{x:6}],test3:[{x:7}]]]
]
```

How can I get to this array?

Comment: Your code is invalid. You have no commas separating the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You want `y` to be the key. You can just use object destructuring like:

```
const {y, ...obj} = row[title];
const fixedRow = {[y]: obj};
```

In this way `y` gets removed from the object, and you can use the previous value of `y` as key and the remaining properties as value.

This won't look exactly like your expected result, because arrays can't have properties, but I suppose it's just a typo.